# Unable to overwrite react-h5-audio-player scss variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I've just included [react-h5-audio-player](https://github.com/lhz516/react-h5-audio-player) into my project and following the *README* page to customise the styles by overwriting the SCSS variables responsible for the colours.
However it seems like my styles just get ignored. Do you have any idea what could be going wrong here? Thank you very much.

This is the codesandbox where I've reproduced the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-and-scss-forked-yeu0q?file=/src/index.js

As you can see I've included the `style.css` (which contains the overwritten variables) in 3 places -- before importing audioplayer's js, before importing audioplayer's css and after both of these just in case to see if any of these works. I also randomly added `!default` and `!important` to the variables hoping that at least some of the syntax would work, but the styles are just keep being ignored.

I will also include the code to this post if someone prefers seeing it here rather in codesandbox:

style.css:

```
html,
body {
  background-color: papayawhip;
  font-family: sans-serif;

  h1 {
    color: tomato;
  }
}

$rhap_theme-color: #ff0000;   // Color of all buttons and volume/progress indicators
$rhap_background-color: #ff0000 !important; // Color of the player background
$rhap_bar-color: #ff0000 !default;     // Color of volume and progress bar
$rhap_time-color: #0000ff !important !default;       // Font color of current time and duration
$rhap_font-family: inherit !important;   // Font family of current time and duration
```

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.scss";

import AudioPlayer from "react-h5-audio-player";

import "./styles.scss";

import "react-h5-audio-player/src/styles.scss";

import "./styles.scss";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <AudioPlayer src="http://example.com/audio.mp3" />
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 1):

For another approach you can use this example:

```
.rhap_container {
  background: #f7f7f9;
}

.rhap_controls-section {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.rhap_progress-section {
  height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.rhap_main-controls-button {
  width: 80px !important;
  height: 80px !important;
}

.rhap_main-controls-button {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  display: block;
}

.rhap_main-controls-button svg {
  color: #ff5555;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.rhap_progress-filled,
.rhap_progress-indicator {
  background-color: #ff5555 !important;
}

.rhap_button-clear.rhap_volume-button {
  color: #ff5555 !important;
}

.rhap_volume-bar, .rhap_volume-indicator {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use **index.css** file in root where I could rewrite player styles that import from **styles.css**:

```
.rhap_progress-section .rhap_progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.2rem 0;
}

.rhap_progress-section .rhap_time {
  color: red;
  font-size: red;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

nested specify classes need to avoid using **!important**.